# Why VertexBuffer is faster than DynamicVertexBuffer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

I've been doing some XNA programming (DirectX) on Windows Phone 7 and noticed that the VertexBuffer class is 30 times faster than the DynamicVertexBuffer class. What's the difference between them anyways? Why the significant speedup when using VertexBuffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN entry for the DynamicVertexBuffer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.dynamicvertexbuffer.aspx) states:

> " Use DynamicVertexBuffer for dynamic
>   vertex arrays and VertexBuffer for
>   non-dynamic vertex arrays...In
>   situations where your game frequently
>   modifies a vertex buffer, it is
>   recommended that the buffer be
>   instantiated or derived from
>   DynamicVertexBuffer instead of the
>   VertexBuffer class.
>   DynamicVertexBuffer is optimized for
>   frequent vertex data modification."

So, its presumably the usual tradeoff of something like a fixed allocated array representation versus a dynamic list.